# observeEvent Shiny function used in a module does not work

Tags: r, module, shiny, shiny-server

I'm developing an app in which I use modules to display different tab's ui content. However it seems like the module does not communicate with the main (or parent) app. It displays the proper ui but is not able to execute the `observeEvent` function when an `actionButton` is clicked, it should update the current tab and display the second one.

In my code I have created a namespace function and wrapped the `actionButton`'s id in `ns()`, however it still does not work. Does anyone knows what's wrong?

```
library(shiny)

moduleUI <- function(id){

  ns <- NS(id)
      sidebarPanel(

        actionButton(ns("action1"), label = "click")
      )
}

module <- function(input, output, session){


  observeEvent(input$action1, {
    updateTabItems(session, "tabsPanel", "two")
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(

            navlistPanel(id = "tabsPanel",

                         tabPanel("one",moduleUI("first")),
                         tabPanel("two",moduleUI("second"))
))
server <- function(input, output, session){
  callModule(module,"first")
  callModule(module,"second")

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The observeEvent works, but since modules only see and know the variables given to them as input parameters, it does not know the tabsetPanel specified and thus cannot update it. This problem can be solved using a reactive Value, which is passed as parameter and which is changed inside the module. Once it's changed, it is known to the main app and can update the tabsetPanel:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

moduleUI <- function(id){

  ns <- NS(id)
  sidebarPanel(
    actionButton(ns("action1"), label = "click")
  )
}

module <- function(input, output, session, tabsPanel, openTab){

  observeEvent(input$action1, {
    if(tabsPanel() == "one"){  # input$tabsPanel == "one"
      openTab("two")
    }else{                     # input$tabsPanel == "two"
      openTab("one")
    }
  })

  return(openTab)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  h2("Currently open Tab:"),
  verbatimTextOutput("opentab"),
  navlistPanel(id = "tabsPanel",
               tabPanel("one", moduleUI("first")),
               tabPanel("two", moduleUI("second"))
  ))


server <- function(input, output, session){
  openTab <- reactiveVal()
  observe({ openTab(input$tabsPanel) }) # always write the currently open tab into openTab()

  # print the currently open tab
  output$opentab <- renderPrint({
    openTab()
  })

  openTab <- callModule(module,"first", reactive({ input$tabsPanel }), openTab)
  openTab <- callModule(module,"second", reactive({ input$tabsPanel }), openTab)

  observeEvent(openTab(), {
    updateTabItems(session, "tabsPanel", openTab())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help shosaco, I now have a better grasp of what's happening. However it seems like this solution only works once. If you click the button, then go back in the first tab and re-click it, nothing happens

Comment: yes, it was just a minimal example, we only changed the open tab to "two" and never back to one. Updated my example accordingly. Trick: Give the module the information about the currently open tab (`input$tabsPanel`), however, this must be wrapped as a reactive, I called it `tabsPanel`. The module then can always knows the open tab by calling `tabsPanel()`. It is explained here: https://www.rstudio.com/resources/webinars/understanding-shiny-modules/ (around 42:15)

Comment: I can't implement input$tabsPanel in my code so that the app always knows on what tab it is. In your example, if you click the button once then go back to the first tab not by using the button, then the app doesn't know you're on a new tab and the button does not work. I don't know how to make sure the app knows at any time which tab is open

Comment: I made a small improvement to the code in the answer to incorporate that (added the line `observe({ openTab(input$tabsPanel) })`).

Comment: @shosaco, why you are doing ` openTab <- reactiveVal()  observe({ openTab(input$tabsPanel) })` for assigning, instead of `openTab<- reactiveVal() ` and then `openTab<-input$tabsPanel`?

Comment: you cannot assign a reactive value outside a reactive context, that's why I have to use `observeEvent` to update openTab() value.

Comment: try it and you will get an error message, because you need the reactive context of `observe` to access an input value.

Comment: @shosaco how can I pass the values (tabsPanel, openTab) as datalist and not directly something like  `openTab <- callModule(NextbuttonServer, "second",  data = list( reactive({input$tabsPanel}),openTab)) ` I get error when I try this. I would like to let the user pass the tab ids, one, two or three based on how he wants to navigate on a click button.